# Question about Export in "Table" format

Tags: export

I want to use a Python software which reads data in columns from an ASCII File. 
The Problem is that each new line shoud be seperated only by `"\n"` and not by `"\n\r"` as in files which `Export[filename, data, "Table"]`does.

Question: **Is it possible to `Export` data with Mathematica by specifying that only `"\n"` should be used at end of each line?**

Comment: @:glS, Community: Thank you for the link to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OpenWrite` in such cases.

```
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 3}];

f = OpenWrite["data.dat"];

Do[
 WriteString[f, StringJoin[{ToString[#], "  "} & /@ data[[n]], "\n"]]
 , {n, Length[data]}]
```

Usually, I use it when I have a long cycle and I want my data to be written in each cycle. So I keep the `Do`/`Table` structure.

You can further use `NumberForm` or any format or delimiter (I use  "  " here) with your data which makes a nice Fortran/Python looking data table.

Comment: I used a hex editor (HxD for Windows) and looked into the file `data.dat`. Each line still ends with `0D0A` which is `\n\r`.

Comment: Try `WriteString[f, StringJoin@Table[{{ToString[#], "  "} & /@ data[[n]], "\n"}
   , {n, Length[data]}]]`